# R shiny fileInput - backslashes leading to upload error

Tags: r, file-io, shiny, backslash

I am having difficulties in R Shiny with the fileInput. I am able to successfully upload multiple .txt or .csv files, however I want my application to be able to upload a filetype called ".fcs" files as well. In order to read such ".fcs" files, I have used the library flowCore under the bioConductor package. Within this flowcore package, there is a function called read.FCS that I often use to read in ".fcs" files into R.

The first argument of the read.FCS() function is a character string of the location of the file. This is where my issue lies: because the function needs the filepath to be in a charcater string, the backslashes in the datapath generated by fileInput() don't mesh with the character string expected by read.FCS (for example, when I print the datapath acquired from fileInput, Shiny returns something like: ...\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtm...PdV/99...42/0 - note the forward and backslashes).

My question is: is there any way to modify the datapath to not include backslashes, so that the read.FCS() function can work properly?

To illustrate this proble, I will attach a simplified version of my scripts below for debugging purposes, as well as a method to generate a .txt file and a .fcs file (you must first install the package flowCore). You will be able to read these both into R, but the .fcs file will be incapable of being read into the Shiny app. Upon launching shiny, when you select the “.txt” File Type option and upload the sample .txt file (generate below),Shiny heads this file. When you relaunch the app and select the “.fcs” file type option and upload the sample .fcs file (generated below), the file does not properly upload.

At first I thought this was Shiny corrupting the FCS file somehow upon upload. But this is not the case. As prrof,  in the mainTab area you will see a printed file path. If you copy this filepath (when you have attempted to load the fcs file), put it in quotes and put it into the read.FCS(insert copied file path with quotes around it here), you will get an error. If, on the other hand, you replace all of the “\” with “/” in the read.FCS command and try it again, R will successfully read the file that was uploaded to Shiny. Thus, I am led to believe that if I could somehow replace the “\” with “/” in the filepath, I will be able to read my FCS files.

Thanks so much for the help – I really appreciate it: sample code attached below

```
install.packages(flowCore)
library(flowCore)

x = rnorm(n=20, mean=5, sd=10)
y = rnorm(n=20, mean=5, sd=10)
z = rnorm(n=20, mean=5, sd=10)
data<-data.frame(as.integer(x),as.integer(y),as.integer(z))
my_save_path<-"C:/Users/drew/Desktop/"
write(as.matrix(data), paste(my_save_path, "sample_textfile.txt", sep=""), ncolumns=3, sep="\t")
df.export<-new("flowFrame", as.matrix(data))
write.FCS(df.export, paste(my_save_path, "sample_fcsfile.fcs", sep=""))
#write.fcs is experimental, but the problem persists for raw .fcs files from other sources other than this export.

#####Verify that these files are real and can be looked at in r

txt.real<-read.delim(paste(my_save_path,"sample_textfile.txt", sep=""))
txt.real #yup, reading into R works

fcs.real<-read.FCS( paste(my_save_path, "sample_fcsfile.fcs", sep=""), transform=FALSE)
fcs.real<-exprs(fcs.real)
fcs.real #yup, this is real too
```

User Interface

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("App",
tabPanel("Overview",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel("Load in Data",
                                           selectInput("filetype", label = h3("File Type"), 
                                                       choices=list(".fcs file", ".txt file"), selected=".txt file"),
                                           fileInput("files", h3("File(s) Input"))),
                              mainPanel(
                                tableOutput("table1"),
                                textOutput("text")                                
                              )))
))
```

Server

```
library(flowCore)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  fileName<-reactive({
    inFile <- input$files
    inFile$datapath
  })

  dataInput<-reactive({

    if(input$filetype==".fcs file"){
      library(flowCore)
      FCS<-read.FCS(fileName(), transform=FALSE)
      exprs(FCS)

    }

    if(input$filetype==".txt file") {
      TXT<-read.delim(fileName())
      TXT
    }
 })

  ####Heading the Table (debug)  
  output$table1<-renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$files))
      return(NULL)

    head(dataInput())

  })

  #Seeing the file path
  output$text<-renderText({
    x<-fileName()
    x
  })

}
)
```